# Count objects in jsonb array with Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

Assume that every jsonb value in a table have this structure:

```
{
  "level1": [
    {
      "level2": [
        {
          "key": key,
          "value": value,
          "messages": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "key": key,
          "value": value,
          "messages": [

          ]
        },
        {
          "key": key,
          "value": value,
          "messages": [

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The names of key `level1` is dynamic, so can be anything (that's why I'm using the `jsonb_object_keys`).
I need to check if any object inside `level2.messages` is empty per date.
That is: if all `level2.messages` in a date are empty, return false. Otherwise (at least one of the objects with message has a non-empty array), return true.

I thought I could use json functions in a subquery, but they are not known inside the subquery.
I have something like this:

```
SELECT t2.date, 
(SELECT 1 FROM fields WHERE jsonb_array_length(fields ->> 'messages') = 1 LIMIT 1) AS hasMessages
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id,
jsonb_object_keys(t1.result) AS rootNode,
jsonb_array_elements(t1.result -> rootNode) AS level2,
jsonb_array_elements(level2 -> 'level2') AS fields
GROUP BY t2.date
```

Comment: Please *always* start with your version of Postgres. Among other things, the arsenal of available tools depends on it. As well as a table definition for `table1` and `table2` - along with an explanation for both tables. Or remove `table2` from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fragmentary info in the question, this would work:

```
SELECT date
     , count(*) AS message_count
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE l2_val->'messages' = '[]') AS empty_message_count
FROM   table1 t1
     , jsonb_object_keys(result) AS key1
     , jsonb_array_elements(result->key1->0->'level2') AS l2_val
GROUP  BY 1
-- HAVING ?
```

This is assuming:

- Always only *one* key name in the outer level of the JSON object.
- Always only *one* array element in `level1`.
- Key name of nested array is `level2`'.

I guess you want to identify those that *do* have messages, but all empty ...